# Multiple IPs on eth0, bridging to VMs and routing

Tags: iptables, routing, kvm-virtualization, bridge

Current situation:

I have a host running 3 virtual machines. One IP for eth0 (xxx.xxx.xxx.239) and one additional for eth0:1 (yyy.yyy.yyy.35). This works fine for me...

```
Host (eth0) (xxx.xxx.xxx.239) | 
                              | <- (virbr0) -> |-- VM1 (10.0.0.21)
                                               |-- VM2 (10.0.0.22)
                                               |-- VM3 (10.0.0.23)
```

...but what I want is to access my third virtual machine addtional by an **external IP (yyy.yyy.yyy.35) on one interface** and by the second **(10.0.0.23) interface for internal purposes**:

```
Host (eth0) (xxx.xxx.xxx.239) | 
                              | <- (virbr0) -> |-- VM1 (10.0.0.21)
                                               |-- VM2 (10.0.0.22)
                                               |-- VM3 (10.0.0.23)

Host (?!?) (?!?)              |
                              |-- VM3 (yyy.yyy.yyy.35)
```

How to realize this and which iptable rules do I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off by first making *eth0* part of a bridge, lets say *phybr0*. Then assigning an additional NIC to your VM which is bridged to *phybr0*. And finally letting the VM have the *yyy.yyy.yyy.35* address assigned to it from within itself, natively. Also, your host machine will then run its *xxx.xxx.xxx.239* IP Address on *phybr0*, and not *eth0*. This could be a starting point: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#public_bridge .

Otherwise, for a solution involving NAT, look at *iptables DNAT*. That is fairly simple to implement and examples from the iptables' man page should suffice. I, however, would make myself aware of the limitations of NAT first.